# Access denied to camera and microphone in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, webcam, microphone

I am trying to create a simple webcam/microphone capture project and keep getting the "Access denied to capture devices" exception. After spending hours searching, I could not find any deviations of the following code:

```
private System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource CaptureSource { get; set; }

private void LayoutRoot_Loaded (object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.CaptureSource = new System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource();

    this.CaptureSource.VideoCaptureDevice = System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();
    this.CaptureSource.VideoCaptureDevice.DesiredFormat = this.CaptureSource.VideoCaptureDevice.SupportedFormats.FirstOrDefault(f => ((((int) f.FramesPerSecond) == 30) && (f.PixelWidth == 640) && (f.PixelHeight == 480)));

    this.CaptureSource.AudioCaptureDevice = System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultAudioCaptureDevice();
    this.CaptureSource.AudioCaptureDevice.DesiredFormat = this.CaptureSource.AudioCaptureDevice.SupportedFormats.FirstOrDefault(f => ((((int) f.BitsPerSample) == 16) && (f.SamplesPerSecond == 44100) && (f.Channels == 2) && (f.WaveFormat == System.Windows.Media.WaveFormatType.Pcm)));

    if ((System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess) || (System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess()))
    {
        this.CaptureSource.CaptureImageCompleted += CaptureSource_CaptureImageCompleted;
        this.CaptureSource.CaptureFailed += CaptureSource_CaptureFailed;

        this.CaptureSource.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("We do not have permission to access your capture devices.", "Review Track", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

A lot of threads mention running the application without the debugger attached. However, in my case no matter what I do, Silverlight does not show the camera/mic permission dialog and just silently crashes or raises an exception in the presence of a debugger.

I have tried this with VS2010, VS2013, Windows 7, 8 and 8.1. I even tried making registry changes to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowWebcam=0x00000001. No effect.

Another article suggested making changes to the silverlight group policy but it does not seem to be present on any of my systems. I have Chrome and IE with the latest upgrades, the OS is up to date and Solverlight is version 5.1.20513.0. Not sure if it matters but all my machiines are 64 bit.